# WaitFor() - How to wait for a specific buffer to arrive on Steam/SerialPort?

Tags: c#, stream, serial-port, tcp

Requested Behaviour: I would like to hear proposed, generic solutions for suspending a calling thread until a specific buffer is received on a Stream/SerialPort. For the time being, I'm not concerned with timeouts etc, however I need something robust.

Attempted method:

```
    Class myClass
    {
        private SerialPort _port; //Assume configured and connected.

        public void WaitFor(byte[] buffer)
        {            
            int bufferLength = buffer.Length;
            byte[] comparisonBuffer = new byte[bufferLength];

            while(true)
            {
                if(_port.BytesToRead >= bufferLength)
                {
                    _port.Read(comparisonBuffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    if (comparisonBuffer.SequenceEqual(buffer)) { return; }
                }
            }
        }
     {
```

I've had a reasonable amount of success with this however it just has a "hacky" feel to it. It has quite often caused me trouble. I believe it's due to the fact that I cannot guarantee that other data isn't received either before or after the expected packet, so naturally this method can end up reading off the stream out of sync. In such a case I would not want to loose the leading/trailing data but the method should release the thread.

I need to implement in a procedural nature so event driven methods won't really work for me. In the generic sense I want to be able to implement as;

```
    Do thing;
    WaitFor(mybuffer);
    Do other thing;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think to this solution?

```
public override byte[] WaitFor(byte[] buffer, int timeout)
{
    // List to stack stream into
    List<byte> stack = new List<byte>();
    // Index of first comparison byte
    int index = 0;
    // Index of last comparison byte
    int upperBound = buffer.Length - 1;
    // Timeout Manager
    Stopwatch Sw = new Stopwatch();

    Sw.Start();
    while (Sw.Elapsed.Seconds <= timeout)
    {
        // Read off the last byte receievd and add to the stack
        stack.Add((byte)_port.ReadByte());

        // If my stack contains enough bytes to compare to the buffer
        if (stack.Count > upperBound)
        {
            // If my first comparison byte matches my first buffer byte
            if (stack[index] == buffer[0])
            {
                // Extract the comparison block to array
                byte[] compBuffer = stack.GetRange(index,upperBound +1).ToArray();

                // If the comparison matches, break and return the redundent bytes should I wish to handle them.
                if ((compBuffer.SequenceEqual(buffer) && (index-1 > 0))) { return stack.GetRange(0, index - 1).ToArray(); }
                // If there were no redundent bytes, just return zero.
                else if (compBuffer.SequenceEqual(buffer)) { return new byte[] { 0}; }  
            }

            // Increments
            index += 1;
            upperBound += 1;
        }

    }

    throw new TimeoutException("Timeout: Expected buffer was not received prior to timeout");
}
```

Comment: @Sir Rufo

Thoughts Sir? Many Thanks.

Comment: This method only waits for a single byte and not for the whole sequence. IMHO is does not answer your question. If you want a code review you should ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Apologies, missed my while loop off. Ah, didn't know about codereview, thanks for the tip. Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

`SerialPort.Read()` already blocks until at least one byte has arrived. Therefore you don't need to (and shouldn't) use the `BytesToRead` the way you are - you've introduced a HORRIBLE busy-wait loop.

Instead, do something like this:

```
// Reads 'count' bytes from a serial port into the specified
// part of a buffer. This blocks until all the bytes have been read.

public void BlockingRead(SerialPort port, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    while (count > 0)
    {
        // SerialPort.Read() blocks until at least one byte has been read, or SerialPort.ReadTimeout milliseconds
        // have elapsed. If a timeout occurs a TimeoutException will be thrown.
        // Because SerialPort.Read() blocks until some data is available this is not a busy loop,
        // and we do NOT need to issue any calls to Thread.Sleep().

        int bytesRead = port.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        offset += bytesRead;
        count -= bytesRead;
    }
}
```

Here's how you would implement your original code in terms of `BlockingRead()`:

```
public void WaitFor(SerialPort port, byte[] buffer)
{
    byte[] comparisonBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length];

    while (true)
    {
        BlockingRead(port, comparisonBuffer, 0, comparisonBuffer.Length);

        if (comparisonBuffer.SequenceEqual(buffer))
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Point taken on constantly re-evaluating `BytesToRead`, but what you've written here doesn't provide the functionality I asked for.

Assume you enter your function with 10 bytes available on the port, and thus count = 10. At the end count will be brought to 0 by `count -= bytesRead` and the loop released.

Now I'm no longer awaiting regardless of what I've received. Your function doesn't do anymore than `port.Read()`.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Yes it does, it reads the number of bytes you've asked it to read, i.e. the passed-in `count` parameter. `SerialPort.Read()` only reads the number of bytes available at the time that it's called. But re-reading your question, it seems that what you're asking for is something different...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read blocks of `count` bytes until a block matches the contents of a target array - is that correct? And you will be throwing away any unmatched blocks.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I see that. To achieve this I could also configure the `ReceivedBytesThreshold` property wait for the `DataReceived` event.

I'm actually looking to identify a particular packet within the incoming buffer and release upon receiving it.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: You're right there, yes. But to complicate it I don't want to throw away and data :P

Comment: Thanks for the edit, however;

"I believe it's due to the fact that I cannot guarantee that other data isn't received either before or after the expected packet, so naturally this method can end up reading off the stream out of sync"

Imagine my steam sits as: xxxxMyPacketxxxxxxx

Whereby x is any other byte. If I use your (or my) code here I'd be looking to read 8 bytes of from this Rx, giving "xxxxMyPa" which != "MyPacket".

I think I may have to run through byte by byte whilst maintaining a bool to say if the comparison is going successfully.

Comment: For example; iterate through the Rx buffer until I find buffer[0], then check the subsequent buffer.count bytes for equality, returning true if they're all there...

What do you think?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I think you'll need to rethink this. Even if you could pick out your message from all the other bytes, what about the other bytes? Who should consume them? It sounds like you haven't tied down your protocol sufficiently.

Comment: I think you're right. At least the answer from Sir Rufo maintains the heading bytes in a list, but I'll still need to handle that somehow and return them. 99 Times from 100 I'll be happy to dispose them, but I'll keep working on it.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Lets assume you wait for the byte pattern `{1,1,1,2,2}` and the serial port has buffered `{1,1,1,1,2,2,5}`.

Your code reads the first 5 bytes `{1,1,1,1,2}` which will not match the pattern. But after reading from the port the data you read has been removed from the buffer and contains only `{2,5}` and you will never get a match.

## Solution

```
public void WaitFor( byte[ ] buffer )
{
    if ( buffer.Length == 0 )
        return;

    var q = new List<byte>( buffer.Length );

    while ( true )
    {
        var current = _reader.ReadByte();
        q.Add( (byte)current );
        // sequence match so far
        if ( q.Last == buffer[ q.Count - 1 ] )
        {
            // check for total match
            if ( q.Count == buffer.Length )
                return;
        }
        else
        {
            // shift the data
            while ( q.Any() && !q.SequenceEqual( buffer.Take( q.Count ) ) )
            {
                q.RemoveAt( 0 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks.

I was starting to think this way (read the last comment of the previous answer).

Thank you very much.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood But what about all the bytes you may have skipped? Haven't you now thrown them away? If they aren't important, why are they being transmitted?

Comment: @MatthewWatson That should be part of a different question :o)

Comment: I agree, but this looks very much like an X-Y question - the solution he's asking for seems wrong, and I suspect it's because there's a deeper malaise.